# Sending an email with Django; CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: python, django, email, csrf

I'm having some issues with CSRF tokens in my Django project.
What I am trying to do is allow a user to send a file to a specific email address using a form on my website. 
The issue is the proverbial "CSRF token missing or incorrect".
I've sifted through a few other questions; however it seems as though my application is built differently than these other ones. I am still very new to Web Development, let alone Django. I think it may have to do with something in views, but it seems none of these solutions are useful for my purposes.
If anyone has any idea of how we can put in the CSRF token or correct here, here are the files that were modified in order to add this email functionality:

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django import forms
from ReadMyPaper.feedbackEmail.forms import EmailForm

#Create your views here.
def send_email(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EmailForm()
        return render_to_response('email.html', {'email_form': form})

    form = EmailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)      
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        attach = request.FILES['attach']
        try:
            mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email])
            mail.attach(attach.name, attach.read(), attach.content_type)
            mail.send()
            #return render_to_response('Email.html', {'message': 'Sent email to %s'%email})
            args = {}
            args.update(csrf(request))
            args['form'] = EmailForm()
            #return render_to_response('email.html' , args)
            #return render_to_response(
            #'email.html', args
            #context_instance=RequestContext(request)
            return render_to_response("email.html", args)


        except:
      #     return render_to_response('admin/Error.html', {'message': 'Either the attachment is too  big or corrupt'})
            return render_to_response('loggedin.html')
```

forms...

```
from django import forms

class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    attach = forms.Field(widget = forms.FileInput)
    message = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
```

template...

```
{% block content %}
{{message}}
{% if email_form %}
<form method="POST" action ="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
<br></br>
{{email_form.as_p}}

<label>&nbsp;</label><label>&nbsp;</label><label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type ="submit"  name = "send" value = "Send"/>
</form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

And the settings file...

```
#settings.py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

# Host for sending e-mail.
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

# Port for sending e-mail.
EMAIL_PORT = 587

# Optional SMTP authentication information for EMAIL_HOST.
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ‘myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ‘mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Obviously those are not the real email and password for gmail address. I have an actual gmail I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `render_to_response()` calls with the `render()`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

return render(request, 'email.html', {'email_form': form})
```

Or pass the `RequestContext` instance to the `render_to_response()`:

```
return render_to_response("email.html", {'email_form': form},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The token worked. I'm assuming this is because it automatically uses RequestContext? That was the issue we had found when we researched this, however, the advice to use "render" never came up. Thanks for your help. We are having now a small issue with the email not sending, but that is a whole new can of worms...thank you!!

Comment: Yes, if you don't pass the `RequestContext` to the `render()` call then it creates such context instance automatically.